# Satisfying P_i for mappings onto a function

Tags: combinatorics, functions

[image]

Why does it **not** satisfy $P_2$ or $P_3$? $i$ isn't equal to $f(i)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not satisfy $P_2$, because there exist $j = 1$ such that $f(j) = f(1) = 2$

The fact that $f(2) \neq 2$ is irrelevant to this property